# Pyramid Framework including models.py from addon to main application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying to create a pyramid framework authentication addon/Plugin. The Plugin needs to have a database that stores user logins and other data, so if a user uses my addon his database must contain certain tables/models from the addon. e.g this Users table

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(Text())
    user_firstname = Column(Text())
    user_lastname = Column(Text())
    user_email = Column(Text())
    user_password = Column(Text())
    user_registrationdate = Column(DateTime())
    user_email_key = Column(Text())
    user_email_key_date_created = Column(DateTime())
    user_email_approved = Column(Boolean())
    user_email_sent = Column(Boolean())
    user_active_account = Column(Boolean())
    user_banned = Column(Boolean())
    user_banned_reason = Column(Text())
```

I need this model to be included in the users main app, i am guessing i have to include something in my includeme shown below

```
def includeme(config):
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
    config.add_route('pyramid.admin', '/pyramid/admin')

    #static views
    config.add_static_view('assets', 'pyramidadmin:static/assets/')

    config.scan('pyramidadmin.views')
```

but i have no Idea what to do. Is there a way i can merge the Base and DBSession from my addon to the base in the main application so that if a user runs `../bin/initialize_myapp_db` the tables from myaddon and from the main app are all created?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DBSession = None

def get_sa_base(engine):
    sabase = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
    sabase.metadata.reflect(engine)
    return sabase

def includeme(config):
    global DBSession
    engine = sqlalchemy.engine_from_config(config.registry.settings)
    if DBSession is None:
        DBSession = orm.scoped_session(
            orm.sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
    DBSession.remove()
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base = get_sa_base(engine)

    # example:
    Base.metadata.tables.values()
```

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/uralbash/sacrud/blob/master/sacrud/pyramid_ext/__init__.py).

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same problem myself.  I'm still working with trying to my stuff more pluggable, but with mixed results.  The way I tackled this problem was to bind each declarative base class with the same engine.  In my generic [scaffolding](https://github.com/umeboshi2/trumpet/blob/master/trumpet/scaffolds/trumpet/%2Bpackage%2B/__init__.py_tmpl) I do this:

```
# create db engine
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
# setup db.sessionmaker
settings['db.sessionmaker'] = DBSession
# bind session to engine
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
# bind objects to engine
Base.metadata.bind = engine
from trumpet.models.base import Base as TrumpetBase
TrumpetBase.metadata.bind = engine
if settings.get('db.populate', 'False') == 'True':
    from mslemon.models.main import make_test_data
    import mslemon.models.misslemon
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    TrumpetBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
    #initialize_sql(engine)
```